# Why is the Fermi Golden rule called so?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, terminology, history, perturbation-theory, fermis-golden-rule

I was studying time dependent perturbation theory and this rule came under the case of constant (weak) perturbations. I understood the rule and the derivation but what I cannot understand is that is that why is it called 'golden'?
I have searched a lot but still cannot get anything about the history or the nomenclature of the rule.

Comment: "The rule was first derived by Dirac. However, it was Fermi who conferred the title golden on the rule, possibly because of its instrumental role in his most cherished theory of Beta decay."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just in case you are not a native speaker of English, the phrase "golden rule" is an idiom which refers to a rule which is cherished or otherwise held in high regard.  Essentially, something made of gold is very special.

As for why he may have regarded that rule as being "golden", Farcher answers that question in the comments:

> The rule was first derived by Dirac. However, it was Fermi who conferred the title golden on the rule, possibly because of its instrumental role in his most cherished theory of Beta decay.

Expanding on that a bit, the rule is crucial because it ultimately yields the only thing we ever measure in a large class of experiments, namely *scattering and decay rates*. We very often probe subatomic particles via scattering experiments, and Fermi's Golden Rule is the tool which allows us to compare the results of those experiments to predictions from the theory.  In other words, it's very, very important.